# Dynamically removing rows from an html table, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and JavaScript, so forgive my basic questions.  I am writing a view that displays several rows of data and at the end of each row I am displaying a Remove button.  When clicked, the button runs some JavaScript that removes the row using the .remove().

When I click the Remove button, the row is removed, but when I return to the controller, any rows below the row that was deleted is not transferred back to the controller and the count is one less then the row I deleted.  For example if I have 6 rows and delete row 4, when I submit back to the controller, the count is 3 and rows 5 and 6 are missing. Not sure why.  Below is my View and controller.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Contacts", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label>Last Name</label></th>
            <th><label>First Name</label></th>
            .... // more table headings
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].LASTNAME)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[j].DOB_NBR)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[j].LASTNAME)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].FIRSTNAME)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[j].FIRSTNAME)
                    </td>
                    .... // more controls
                    <td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
                j++;
            }
        }
    </table>
    <input type="button" class="add-button btn btn-default" name="add" value="Add" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Please double check all information before submitting.   Submit Notification?')" />
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(string submitAction, List<ENTITY_CONTACTS> entity_Contacts)
{
    // entity_Contacts is not bound with all items in the collection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind collections when the indexers are zero-based and consecutive. In your case, when you remove the 4th row, your indexers are 0, 1, 2, 4 and 5 so only the first 3 are bound. You can override this behavior by adding a hidden input for the indexer, which allows the `DefaultModelBinder` to match up non-consecutive indexers.

Change your loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) // do not use a foreach loop
{
    <tr class="contacts-record">
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="Index" value="@i" /> // add this
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[i].LASTNAME)
            @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[i].DOB_NBR)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[i].LASTNAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>
        .... // other td elements
    <tr>
}
```

For more information on binding to collections, refer [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/), and if your also looking to dynamically add items to the collections, refer the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Side note: remove the `id` attribute from your 'Delete' button. Your creating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. Also remove the scripts for `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` because you have already added them using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`, however you need to ensure that `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` is rendered first, preferably using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`. In addition, all the scripts should be inside `@section Scripts {`

Comment: Thanks for the reply that is exactly what I was looking for.  I started to create the delete using the .hide(), but your response is much easer.  I do have an additional question.  Below is my add function.  How do I assign a new value to Index?

Comment: If you have a new question, then you need to ask a new question, but before you do, I suggest you look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) to understand how to dynamically add and remove collection items - and I just noticed I already had those links in my answer :)

Comment: Not only that, but I just realized I gave you those links in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919506/dynamically-adding-rows-to-an-html-table-using-javascript) as well where I pointed out that the answer you accepted would not solve your problem

Comment: Seriously, you want my help on the other question when you don't even find this correct answer useful?